# How to find out usage of a jar in a maven-java project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a large maven project (with modules). There is a main module which gets imported in all other modules. There's a jar - "xml-apis.jar" - added as a dependency in the main module and its added to other modules as well.
Now I want to find out what are the classes in my project uses/imports classes from "xml-apis.jar".

I can try removing the dependency and see the compilation errors. But is there a way to get this a report or a table mapping each class with its import statement?

Comment: Using a good IDE would solve the problem? Searching in IDEA IntelliJ ?... Should be possible in Eclipse as well... And yes removing the dep will fail where it is needed..

Comment: Even if you remove the dependency w/o compilation errors, it might be a _runtime dependency_ and your code could fail when it tries to use it at runtime. So you can't depend on compilation errors (although it's a good start)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation but I need this for the whole project for all the source files rather than for a single file. Opening each source file and trying to search within IDE seems not idle in this situation though.

Comment: Maybe you can get such a table from jqassistant.

Comment: In vscode/Intellij , i can start search on the project root folder with something like import com.xmlapi.... something. Will it not give all files using this jar as import? or am i missing something